# Swagger - "Required @OA\Info() not found"

Tags: php, openapi, swagger-php

I just got into api documentation and tried to use Swagger

here is my php file with routes that I want to document:

```php
<?php

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
 */
return [
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/api/v1/test",
     *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="An example resource")
     * )
     */
    'GET api/v1/test' => 'test/index',
];
```

But when I run `./vendor/bin/openapi api/config/routes.php` cli only outputs errors:

```
Warning: Required @OA\Info() not found
Warning: Required @OA\PathItem() not found
openapi: 3.0.0
```

I then tried Swagger2 and it worked just fine

Im using `php8.1` from `php:8.1-fpm-alpine` docker image, the latest `zircote/swagger-php` package and the Yii2 framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out openapi was not autoloading classes from my subfolders

The solution is very simple: generate docs from inside of a console application (for example I have a `php yii open-api/generate-docs` command)

That way composer and yii2 load all of the classes needed for swagger

You also have to anchor all of the attributes to specific classes so the approach in the original question will not work; my solution was to create a compiled router with each route having a separate class with php8.1 attributes

Comment: where does `open-api/generate-docs` come from?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo this is syntax for running console apps with the yii2 framework; its not tied directly to open-api in any way

Comment: That I know, may be I asked lousily. I was asking where does OpenApiController actually is coming from. Do you write it or is it provided by some package? Your answer isn't very clear when someone want to use it to reach to the solution. Sorry for lousy question at first!

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo yeah i did write it myself but its basically just a call to `\OpenApi\Generator::scan` from the `zircote/swagger-php` package

Answer (score 8):

Here is solution
https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/443

Add in your base Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
 */
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Comment: Thats not a valid solution as it doesnt solve the autoloading issues that i had

Answer (score 2):

I updated the `darkaonline/l5-swagger` for `Laravel` framework and this third-party library is using `zircote/swagger-php` library behind the scene, after updating to version `"darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.5"` I faced a similar issue like bellow.

```
Required @OA\Info() not found
at vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Loggers/DefaultLogger.php
```

I added swagger to the project long before **PHP** introduced Attributes, and at that time, for generating swagger information, annotations were being used therefore you could have files only containing **annotations** (which by the way for a big project, having **shared components** is a lifesaver).

For example, you could separate different types of **shared components** in their own files, in this way maintaining a project that offers swagger documentation will be way much easier, and this method was working just fine.
I had some files for **core** like `@OA\Info` and **shared components** like below.

```
<?php

/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title="API Documentation",
 *      description="Description removed for better illustration of structure.",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="admin@example.test",
 *          name="company",
 *          url="https://example.test"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\License(
 *          name="Apache 2.0",
 *          url="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
 *      )
 * )
 */
```

After updating the library, the mentioned error roused and the cause is that an `annotation` is basically documentation or comment text, thus the programming language automatically ignores it, therefore the `@OA` phrase is basically just a text and not anything more.

After **PHP** introduced **Attributes** the third-party library developer tried to support attributes as well, and since an attribute is carrying metadata and it's handled by **PHP** itself, it needs to get attached to some concept like `class` or `function`, it seems the developer didn't see some edge case and the so-called edge case is the applications using `annotations` for a long time, may implement them in separate files only containing the documentation or comment, and no other programming concepts like `function` or any other thing.

Therefore to fix the issue I just needed to change the files containing the **annotations** into **class files** and add some empty classes under the documentation and autoload the created classes.

In this way, the third-party library reads the annotations like before.

So I renamed the `setup.php` file to `Setup.php` as `PSR-4` the autoloading standard requires for class names and updated the content like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Your\Path\Swagger;

/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title="API Documentation",
 *      description="Description removed for better illustration of structure.",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="admin@example.test",
 *          name="company",
 *          url="https://example.test"
 *      ),
 *      @OA\License(
 *          name="Apache 2.0",
 *          url="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
 *      )
 * )
 */
final class Setup
{
    //
}
```

after converting the file into a class, I just had to tell the composer to automatically load classes in the `App/Your/Path/Swagger` path in the `composer.json` file like below.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "App/Your/Path/Swagger",
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

In this way, the problem is solved. just remember that if you have **shared component** files, you need to change them too.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also add `-b ./vendor/autoload.php` to the `openapi` command to setup autoloading for swagger-php.

Either way I am surprised that this works with swagger-php v4 as that requires annotations to be anchored to a structural element (class, interface, etc.)

The main idea here is to annotate your actual controllers (or whatever it is called in your framework), so the code that handles a request so the documentation is close to the actual code.

Comment: yeah, sorry, forgot to mention that I created a compiled router that anchors all routes to specific classes; also, plain `-b autoload.php` will not work in yii2 since yii2 loads project classes upon initialization so you need to run a console app

Answer (score 1):

In your folder structure create a folder named `Swagger` and create a class named `SwaggerDecorator` and then add this annotations on top of the `SwaggerDecorator`:

```
<?php

namespace Support\Swagger;

/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      title="The Test Api Documentation",
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      description="The Test Api Documentation"
 *  )
 */
class SwaggerDecorator
{
    
}
```

You can choose what ever name and folder name you want.

and now add the following line to the `l5/swagger.php` package config file:

```
return [
    'default' => 'default',
    'documentations' => [
        /// ... other configs
                
            /*
             * Absolute paths to directory containing the swagger annotations are stored.
            */
            'annotations' => [
                base_path('app/Swagger'), // You should add this line to work
                base_path('app/'),
            ],
            
        ],
    //... other configs
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i upgrade `zircote/swagger-php` from 4.7.15 to 4.8.3 and had same issue on one project.

https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/faq.html#warning-required-oa-info-not-found says:

> As of version 4.8 the doctrine/annotations library is optional and might cause the same message.
> If this is the case, doctrine annotations must be installed separately:
> `composer require doctrine/annotations`

One of my projects had `doctrine/annotations` as dependency in another library, but my another project didn't, that caused problems with documentation wrote through PHPDocs.

So you got two options, or require missing dependency or rewrite code as below (PHP8+):

```
/**
 * REST API route base class.
 *
 * @OA\Info(
 *     title="Test API REST",
 *     version="latest",
 *     description="test"
 * )
 */
```

Replace with:

```
#[\OpenApi\Attributes\Info(
    title: "Test API REST",
    version: "latest",
    description: "test",
)]
```