# zircote/swagger-php - Skipping unknown La\Product

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

***Problem***

I'm trying to use `zircote/swagger-php` to generate an OpenApi file from PHP-code. For some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: Skipping unknown La\Product
Warning: Required @OA\PathItem() not found
Warning: Required @OA\Info() not found
```

***Setup***

I'm using a docker container to have it reproducible. My setup is as follows:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── project
│   └── myTest.php
└── swagger.php
```

and here is the contents of the files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM composer:latest
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN ["composer", "require", "zircote/swagger-php"]
RUN ["composer", "require", "doctrine/annotations"]
CMD ["sh"]
```

Inside the container I run: `./vendor/bin/openapi project/`

project/myTest.php

```
<?php

namespace La;
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
 * @OA\Get(
 *    path="/",
 *    @OA\Response(response="200", description="Some description.")
 * )
 */
#[SomeAttribute]
class Product {
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/api/data.json",
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="The data"
     *     )
     * )
     */
    public function getResource()
    {
        // ...
    }
    public $la = 12;
}
```

swagger.php

```
<?php

require("vendor/autoload.php");
$openapi = \OpenApi\Generator::scan(['project']);
header('Content-Type: application/x-yaml');
echo $openapi->toJson();
```

Yields same error as running a command-line command above.

***Have tried***

I have tried several tutorials and examples, with the same output, just different namespaces and class-names being skipped.

I have seen [here](https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/faq.html#skipping-unknown-someclass) that it all comes down to autoloading and reflection, but it didn't give me any practical hints what to do.

I also saw in some [comments](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/443#issuecomment-1028905523) on github that downgrading to php 8.1 helps, but that didn't work for me. After a lot of fiddeling with the Dockerfile, it came down to the exact same error.

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468928/swagger-required-oa-info-not-found) on SO didn't help. Seems to be very Laravel specific.

The suggestion [here](https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/faq.html) to have just one dummy class, yields pretty much the same error, tho there is no class skipped.

Just to make sure that I'm not having something really stupid, I verified that reflection is working with this code:

```
<?php

require './project/myTest.php';

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('La\Product');

$t = new La\Product();
echo $t->la . "\n";

var_dump($reflector->getProperties());
echo "\n";

print_r(array_map(fn($att) => $att->getName(), $reflector->getAttributes()));

var_dump( $reflector->getDocComment());
```

Which gave the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running into this issue: https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/faq.html#skipping-unknown-someclass

You've done pretty much everything correct, except for autoloading. In fact, in your manual example you've actually explicitely `require`'d the test class file for the same reason - the class needs to be loaded for reflection to work.

There are two ways to get this basic test to work

a) Add `myTest.php` as bootstrap option to the CL
This will do the `require` for you, just like in your test code.

```
./vendor/bin/openapi -b project/myTest.php project/
```

b) Set up composer autoloading.
Seems there is no composer.json in your setup. I suppose something like

```yaml
{
    "require": {
        "zircote/swagger-php": "^4.8",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^2.0"
    },
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "La\\": "project/"
        }
    }
}
```

should work. Also means you can change your Dockerfile to a single composer command:

```
RUN ["composer", "install"]
```

It should be clear that option (b) is the more scalable :)

**Final thing about autoloading is that PSR-4 requires the filename to match the classname**, so you'll need to rename `myTest.php` to `Product.php`.

Comment: This is a great help. Thanks. I think you confused the order, and it is `"La\\": "project/"`. But even with this, I'm getting the error that `Skipping unknown La\Product`. With the `-b` option it works perfectly. Just the composer.json doesn't want to make it work. I noticed that for that `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php` is being used, and `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` (which has a correct mapping), is not being run.

Comment: I managed to get it working using `classmap`. Would that be bad? Any idea how to make it work with psr-4? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, got the `psr-4` mapping wrong - updated in my post.
I've also added a note about the requirement for the filename to match the classname. I tried this locally with the fixed `composer.json` and renaming `myTest` to `Product` and that actually makes it work.